# I have a string inside of an object that I'm pushing to an empty array, but I want the string to be shuffled when pushed to the empty array

Tags: javascript, object, shuffle

> String Object

```
let stringObject = {
   upper: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
};
```

> Empty Array to push upper string to

```
let emptyArr = [];
```

> Function to push string to array and shuffle
> When I try to push to the empty array, the string is pushed exactly as it appears in the object, versus being randomly shuffled like I need it to be.

```
 function confirmUpper() {
 // User Confirm Upper Char
 let upperCase = confirm("Would you like upper case characters?");
 
 // If user chooses yes, push upper string to empty array
 if (upperCase === true) {
     function shuffle(s) {
         emptyArr.push(stringObject.upper);
     console.log("Upper Added! ");
         //
         emptyArr.sort(function() {
             return 0.5 - Math.random();
         });
         // Convert Array to string
         s = emptyArr.join('');
         return s;
     }
 
     let s = emptyArr;
 
     s = shuffle(s);
 
     console.log(s);
     
 } else {
     console.log("No Uppers! ")
 }

 
}

confirmUpper();
```

> **Result in the console:**

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: try something like this. `array.push([...str].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())`

Answer (score 0):

What is `stringObject.upper`? Looks like you're pushing the whole string into `emptyArray` (so now emptyArray is `['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']` and then sorting it--there's only one entry so sorting it does nothing--then joining it, which just returns the only entry, which is the original string.

```js
const stringUpper = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

const emptyArray = [];

emptyArray.push(stringUpper); // emptyArray is now ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']

emptyArray.sort( ... ); // emptyArray is still ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'];

const s = emptyArray.join(''); // s is now 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
```

This first problem could be solved by pushing `stringUpper.split('')` into `emptyArray` instead of `stringUpper`, or better yet, just assign it to emptyArray directly:

```js
const emptyArray = stringUpper.split('');

// emptyArray is now  ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
```

Comment: stringObject.upper is the string inside of my object. So, do you recommend I take out the join and sort?

Answer (score 0):

You array is one `string` to shuffle the string use the spread operator and then you could use a simple loop to shuffle each individual character in the array

```js
let stringObject = {
  upper: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
};

let emptyArr = [];


function confirmUpper() {
// User Confirm Upper Char
let upperCase = true

// If user chooses yes, push upper string to empty array
if (upperCase === true) {
    function shuffle(s) {
        emptyArr.push(stringObject.upper);
        var shuff= [...emptyArr[0]]
        //
        for(let i=0;i<shuff.length;i++){
         let k=Math.round(Math.random()*(emptyArr.length-1));
          [shuff[i],shuff[k]]=[shuff[k],shuff[i]];
        }
        s = shuff.join('');
        return s;
    }

    let s = emptyArr;

    s = shuffle(s);

    console.log(s);
    
} else {
    console.log("No Uppers! ")
}


}

confirmUpper();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to split the string before.
Instead of pushing to emtyArr, you can split the string and get it in emptyArr.
Since you are doing sort on the array, and the array has only one object, you are not able to get the randomly sorted array. Array should have multiple elements to sort it. Right ?

```
let stringObject = {
   upper: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
};

let finalArr = [];

function confirmUpper() {
 // User Confirm Upper Char
 let upperCase = confirm("Would you like upper case characters?");
 
 // If user chooses yes, push upper string to empty array
 if (upperCase === true) {
     function shuffle(s) {
        var emptyArr = s.split(''); 
     console.log("Upper Added! ");
         //
         emptyArr.sort(function() {
             return 0.5 - Math.random();
         });
         // Convert Array to string
         s = emptyArr.join('');
         return s;
     }
 
     let s = stringObject.upper;
 
     s = shuffle(s);
    
     // pushing the elements after shuffling
     finalArr.push(s);
 
     console.log(s);
     
 } else {
     console.log("No Uppers! ")
 }

 
}

confirmUpper();
```

Comment: I know this works the way I need it to, but the problem is that I will eventually have more strings in the object, so I will need to push into the empty array among a true response.

Comment: @tydangelo18 : you can add to the finalArr element after shuffling. I updated my answer, see if that solves your issue.